# xframe implementation on the front-end side?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Hi Guys,

How can we implement xframe options on the front end rather than putting it in the header file.

And how can we implement for the entire website so that the website wont load when put in an iframe ?